# Count multiple tables giving me same result

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count

I have two tables and want to get a count for an ID number in both table.  One table will only have one result, but the other could have more.

```
select 
a.ID,
count(a.ID),
count(b.ID)
from a

join b on
(b.ID=a.ID)

where a.ID='7820193'
group by a.ID
```

The results look like this
ID
7820193
count (a.ID)=200
count(b.ID)=200

However, there is only one instance of that ID number in a
I have tried with all types of join (left, right, inner)
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are you exactly want to do here? mysql count function is used for count the total number of records generated by select statement.

Comment: I would like to get the count of how many times the ID is in each table.  In this case its one time in a and 200 times in b.  For some reason I get the same total for each table.

Comment: Run your select statement without count function then see what is happening there.

Comment: I have verified that if I check a for that ID, there is only one.  If I check b for that ID there is 200.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
SELECT
  Derived.id,
  COUNT(*),
  Derived.count

FROM(
  SELECT
    id,
    COUNT(*) AS count

  FROM a

  WHERE id = 7820193
) AS Derived

JOIN b AS b ON b.id = Derived.id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    a.id, 
    count(a.id),
    b.id,
    count(b.id)
from a,b 
where a.id = b.id and a.id = ''7820193'
group by 
    a.id,
    b.id;
```

Comment: run this query.it will give count from both tables.

Answer (score 0):

Try it.

```
SELECT a.ID, COUNT(a.ID) counta, (SELECT COUNT(b.ID) FROM b WHERE b.ID = a.ID  GROUP BY b.ID) AS countb
FROM a 
WHERE a.ID='7820193' GROUP BY a.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the expected result, give a try :)

```
SELECT 
    z.id,
    count(a.id) as count_ID_from_Table_A,
    count(b.id) as count_ID_from_Table_B
FROM
   (SELECT ID FROM table1
    UNION
    SELECT ID FROM table2) z
LEFT JOIN 
    table1 a ON z.id=a.id
LEFT JOIN 
    table2 b ON z.id=b.id
GROUP BY 
    z.id
```